# How to auto adjust draggable text in droppable div left-align

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to drop text in div with `id="drag"` to another div with `id="dropdiv"`. Text in `<p>` tag is getting dropped but not in center or left of droppable div.

I want that whenever I drop text on div it gets automatically adjust itself at center or left of div. Please tell me how to do it. Here is my code:

```
$(".draggable2").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    stop: function () {
        $(this).draggable('option', 'revert', 'invalid');
    }
});

$(".draggable2").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function (event, ui) {        
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
        ui.draggable.position({of: $(this),my: 'left top',at: 'left top'});
    }
});
$(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {

    }
});
```

```html
<div style="text-align:left; border:1px solid;"class="droppable" id="dropdiv"></div>
<div id="drag">
    <p class="draggable2">TEXT</p>
</div>
```

Comment: update the html and css code

Comment: <div style="text-align:left; border:1px solid;"class="droppable" id="dropdiv"></div>
<div id="drag" ><p class="draggable2 " >Text</p><div>

Comment: I've edited your question to fix code-formatting. For future reference: you did it right with the Javascript snippet, but forgot to format your entire HTML code, as well as a stray `<p>` tag in your introductory description. Without formatting, HTML tags will not show up as readable code. You can [format your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) either inline with backticks, or in blocks by using 4 spaces of indentation. Welcome to StackOverflow, this is a nice and answerable question!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need like this? I change script like following, it may help you..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
 
 
    $( ".draggable2" ).draggable();
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).html($( ".draggable2" ).draggable());
        $( this ).find("p").removeAttr("style");
        $( this ).css("height","auto");
      }
    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align:left; border:1px solid;height:20px;"class="droppable" id="dropdiv">
</div> 

<div id="drag" ><p class="draggable2 " >Text</p><div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if there is more than one draggable <p> and each have to drop in different droppable div